# Java application showing unusably small on hi DPI screen

Tags: windows, high-dpi

I have a 4k screen notebook, a Lenovo Yoga 900 to be precise.

We have a Java application that doesn't scale itself to high resolution and seems very very small to on screen.

I changed the Windows DPI settings and as a result, the text in the application are all mixed up.

You can see it in the picture below:

[image]

What else can I try to see enlarged the application?

Comment: The overall system resolution or the per application resolution?

Comment: Welcome on SuperUser Ali. Please [edit] your post adding the windows version. It can help to answer you. Maybe in the meantime you want to read some article [like this one](http://www.tekrevue.com/tip/windows-10-display-scaling/) about scaling display.

Comment: That application is not DPI aware. It needs to be programmed properly to handle changing of DPI.  Contact the author of the software for an updated version that properly supports DPIs other than "100%".